# Stack overflow :return address in little endian

Tags: assembly, x86

This is a typical buffer: `buff = "A" * 2000 + addr_in_little_endien + shellcode`

I wonder why we should write the address in little endian, after all, when our buffer is copied in memory normally it is copied in little endian and when it pushed it become again normal.

Answer (score 3):

Since the buffer is treated as a string by the exploited program, it will be written byte by byte. Thus, the desired contents have to match what you want the memory to end up looking like, i.e. addresses need to be little-endian.